# Title field character length

Tags: entry, validation

Is it possible to limit the title field in an entry?  As with other fields I can adjust so that it only takes a certain amount of characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom validation at the `EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE` event

```
Event::on(Entry::class,
    Entry::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE,
    function(ModelEvent $event){
        /** @var Entry $entry */
        $entry = $event->sender;
        // you can check for the section and the type

        $model = DynamicModel::validateData(['title' => $entry->title], [
            [['title'], 'string', 'max' => 2, 'message'=>'{attribute} should not be longer than 2 characters']
        ]);
        if($model->hasErrors()){
            $entry->addErrors($model->getErrors());
            $event->isValid = false;
        }
});
```

You can leave remove the `message` attribute if you don't want to use a custom error message, I just wanted to provide a full example how to validate data in Yii2. That way you can define whatever rule you want

Comment: Thanks Robin, that is above my dev threshold level :) . I took a look in SavableComponent.php but not sure if that is where I make the change.

Comment: It's actually not that hard. If you are going to create a more complex site you'll need to create plugins. You should read the docs https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/v3/en/plugin-intro.md this change belongs into a module or plugin. There is not really another way to achieve it